# Define new operator in c++

Tags: c++

Can we define our own operator in c++?

I need to define a%%b as (a%b+b)%b because sometimes a%b gives a negative value(-239%5=-4), and I want the positive reminder. So if a%b is negative, add b to a%b and return the value. This can be simply done using (a%b+b)%b.
I tried

```
#define a%%b (a%b+b)%b
```

but it is giving error.
We can do this by using a function

```
int mod(int a, int b){
    return (a%b+b)%b;
}
```

but I want to do this by defining as I do for a 'for' loop

```
#define f(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<b;i++)
```

please suggest me a way to define a%%b as (a%b+b)%b.

Comment: No. You can only overload an existing operator.

Comment: Any decent book, tutorial or class should have said no.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can only overload an existing operator. However, you could wrap an `int` with your own class, and overload `operator%` for this class. [Like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J1XWM5LaLytgl9uG):

```
#include <iostream>

struct int_wrapper {
    explicit int_wrapper(int n) : n_(n)
    { }
    operator int() const {
        return n_;
    }
private:
    int n_;
};

int operator%(int_wrapper lhs, int_wrapper rhs) {
    return ((int)lhs % rhs + rhs) % rhs;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << (int_wrapper(-239) % int_wrapper(5)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's confusing. You have an object that appears to be an `int` (from its name) but has an overloaded '%' operator that behaves similar but different then the build in operator for '%' int

Comment: @bolov I agree. The name should be something like int_with_non_negative_mod. "Ugly notation for an ugly operation", as Stroustrup said :-).